# Error 403 Forbidden when trying to create an Azure Storage Table from Azure Websites

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-table-storage

I am getting the error below when trying to create a new table in a new Azure storage account from Azure Websites. It works when I try to do it from my local machine. It also works when I use my old Azure storage account.

> System.AggregateException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233088   Message=One or more errors occurred.
>   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
>          at MyProject.Data.Repositories.MatchRepository..ctor(CloudStorageAccount
>   storageAccount) in
>   D:\home\site\approot\src\MyProject.Data\Repositories\MatchRepository.cs:line
>   15
>          at MyProject.Startup.ConfigureStorageRepositoriesAndServices(IServiceCollection
>   services, CloudStorageAccount storageAccount) in
>   D:\home\site\approot\src\MyProject\Startup.cs:line 98
>          at MyProject.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in D:\home\site\approot\src\MyProject\Startup.cs:line 86
>   InnerException: 
>          ErrorCode=-2147217005
>          HResult=-2147217005
>          Message= 
>      403
>   Server failed to authenticate the request. Make
>   sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including
>   the signature.
>   Primary
>   0d907af5-0002-0117-126c-ea972b000000
>         Tue, 08 Sep 2015 19:31:47
>   GMT   Tue, 08 Sep 2015 19:31:43
>   GMT   Tue, 08 Sep 2015 19:31:47 GMT
>   
>       `AuthenticationFailed`
>       Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the
>   signature. RequestId:0d907af5-0002-0117-126c-ea972b000000
>   Time:2015-09-08T19:31:46.4165753Z   
>   
>       StorageException
>       -2146233088
>       Unexpected response code, Expected:OK or NotFound, Received:Forbidden
>       Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage
>          at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.<ExecuteAsyncInternal>d__4`1.MoveNext()</StackTrace>
>   </ExceptionInfo> </RequestResult>
>          Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage
>          StackTrace:
>               at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.<ExecuteAsyncInternal>d__4`1.MoveNext()
>            --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>               at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>               at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>               at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable.<>c__DisplayClass51_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>            --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>               at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>               at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>               at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>            --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>               at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>               at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>               at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>               at MyProject.Data.TableRepository.<CreateTableAsync>d__13.MoveNext() in
>   D:\home\site\approot\src\MyProject.Data\Common\TableRepository.cs:line
>   29
>            --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>               at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>               at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>               at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>               at MyProject.Data.Repositories.MatchRepository.d__2.MoveNext()
>   in
>   D:\home\site\approot\src\MyProject.Data\Repositories\MatchRepository.cs:line
>   20
>          InnerException: 
>               HResult=-2146233088
>               Message=Unexpected response code, Expected:OK or NotFound, Received:Forbidden
>               Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage
>               StackTrace:
>                    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.d__4`1.MoveNext()
>               InnerException:

Comment: can you share the code that fails? also does it work locally?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using your manage keys in a wrong way.

web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storagesample;AccountKey=nYV0gln9fT7bvY+rxu2iWAEyzPNITGkhM88J8HUoyofpK7C8fHcZc2kIZp6cKgYRUM74lHI84L50Iau1+9hPjB==" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

c# code:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"]);
```

source:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/

Comment: I think you have a typo, you are setting an app setting but reading a connection string.

Comment: just fix that. Thanks